# Using select/case to select correct date from a certain cell, subtract months listed in another cell and output to a certain row,column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Select/Case that if Column 6 active row matches a certain number then it goes to a certain cell that has a date in m/dd/yyyy format and subtracts the amount of months listed in number format Column 8 for that active row and puts it into Column 9 of that active row.

Issue is after it reads the value of Column 6 and proceeds to S.Cells(E, 9) = p4 - S.Cells(E, 8). It is throwing a mismatch error on Phase4 = S.Cells(2, 13).

Thanks in advance and let me know if I did not explain it correctly :)

Here is a screenshot of the layout.

[image]

```
Dim E As Integer
Dim Phase1 As Integer
Dim Phase2 As Integer
Dim Phase3 As Integer
Dim Phase4 As Integer
Dim Phase5 As Integer
Dim Phase6 As Integer
Dim Phase7 As Integer
Dim Phase8 As Integer
Dim p1 As Date
Dim p2 As Date
Dim p3 As Date
Dim p4 As Date
Dim p5 As Date
Dim p6 As Date
Dim p7 As Date
Dim p8 As Date
''
E = 2
Set S = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
''
'''''''''''''''''''''TUM CALCULATION'''''''''''''''''''''''
             Phase1 = S.Cells(2, 10)
             Phase2 = S.Cells(2, 11)
             Phase3 = S.Cells(2, 12)
             Phase4 = S.Cells(2, 13)
             Phase5 = S.Cells(2, 14)
             Phase6 = S.Cells(2, 15)
             Phase7 = S.Cells(2, 16)
             Phase8 = S.Cells(2, 17)
             '''''''''''''''''''''''
             p1 = DateValue(Phase1)
             p2 = DateValue(Phase2)
             p3 = DateValue(Phase3)
             p4 = DateValue(Phase4)
             p5 = DateValue(Phase5)
             p6 = DateValue(Phase6)
             p7 = DateValue(Phase7)
             p8 = DateValue(Phase8)
             '''''''''''''''''''''''

             Select Case Right(S.Cells(E, 6), 1)
                 Case "1"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p1 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "2"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p2 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "3"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p3 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "4"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p4 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "5"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p5 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "6"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p6 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "7"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p7 - S.Cells(E, 8))
                 Case "8"
                     S.Cells(E, 9) = (p8 - S.Cells(E, 8))
             End Select
```

Comment: Okay, you've stated what _you're trying to do_, but what is the actual problem and your question?

Comment: And `Set S = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)` can be simplified to `Set S = ActiveSheet`. But it's strange that you declared all your other variables but you didn't `Dim S As Worksheet`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the "certain number" and "certain cell" please.  I tried to figure out using the "certain number" of 4 which occurs in rows `2:7`.    But if `E=2` then `Select Case Right(S.Cells(E, 6), 1)` will always look at `F2` rather than a "certain cell".  Then looking at everything else it always looks at row 2... I'm confused.

Comment: Issue is after it reads the value of Column 6 and proceeds to S.Cells(E, 9) = p4 - S.Cells(E, 8). It is throwing a mismatch error on Phase4 = S.Cells(2, 13).

Comment: What's the value in `S.Cells(2,13)`?  Phase4 can only contain an _Integer_ - well, a whole number.  It will return type mismatch with text.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook we use this apart of a much larger macro that loops E = E + 1 at the end telling it to go to the next row and repeat.

Comment: In that case can you read [mcve] please.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook (2,13) is a date.

Comment: With a date you're more likely to get an overflow error using an integer (`Dim Phase4 As Integer`).  What format is the date?

Comment: It is m/dd/yyyy and did not post the entire macro because other parts deal with another application that  I thought could cause confusion, but I can if needed post the entire code.

Comment: If the other Phase dates are processing without an error, and this particular one in `Cells(2,13)` is returning a `Type Mismatch` error, then most likely that particular cell contains the date as a text string.  What is the `.Value2` property of that cell?  If it looks like a date, then you have a text string in the cell.  If it looks like a five digit number, then it is a real date and your type mismatch is coming from someplace else.

Comment: However, the other cells should be giving you an overflow error, since dates are stored as serial numbers with `1 = 1-Jan-1900` and an Integer datatype can only contain up to `2^15`, unless those dates are much earlier (approx. before Nov 1989) than what you show above.